# Javascript Code Not showing on External Websites

Tags: javascript

I have site like 2leep, mgid. When I post widget code on external website, most of time it does not show me the result.

This is the widget code doing problem on external sites.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>wID='26';document.write('<div id=mywidgets26></div>');document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/JavaScript" src="http://www.jugglu.com/widget/bootstrap.js"></scr'+'ipt>');</script>
```

Comment: is the variable wID set on the external site ?

Comment: any one solved this thing ?

Answer (score 0):

try this in javascript :

```
var wID='26';
```

maybe u didnt set the variable in the external website befor u overwrite the value in the code...